# How to remove all the line breaks and paragrah breaks using java for a given text file?

Tags: java, regex, file

I have a huge text file.
I would like to remove all the line breaks and want the paragraphs breaks also to be removed and appended to the previous paragrah. How should I do it using java? I have used replaceALL() in java but i am stuck with getting the paragraph appended to the previous one.

[Please view this image for the file screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8yjR.png)

```
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context ) throws IOException, InterruptedException{ 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            System.out.println(value.toString().replaceAll("[\\t\\n]+", ""));
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString().replaceAll("[\\t\\n]+", ""));        
            String[] tokens = new String[itr.countTokens()*2];

            for(int l = 0 ; l<tokens.length;l++){
                if(itr.hasMoreTokens()){
                    tokens[l] = itr.nextToken();

                }
            }
                    for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
                    if(tokens[i] != null && tokens[i] != " "){
                        sb.append(tokens[i]);
                            for(int j = i+1;j<i+5;j++){
                                if(tokens[j] != null)
                                {
                                sb.append(" ");
                                sb.append(tokens[j]);
                                }

                            }
                    }
                        word.set(sb.toString());
                        context.write(word, one);
                        //System.out.println(sb.toString());
                        sb.setLength(0);

                    }
        }
```

Input:

```
The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Complete Works of William Shakespeare, by
William Shakespeare
sn
This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with
almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or
re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included
with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.org

** This is a COPYRIGHTED Project Gutenberg eBook, Details Below **
**     Please follow the copyright guidelines in this file.     **

Title: The Complete Works of William Shakespeare

Author: William Shakespeare

Posting Date: September 1, 2011 [EBook #100]
Release Date: January, 1994

Language: English


*** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK COMPLETE WORKS--WILLIAM SHAKESPEARE ***




Produced by World Library, Inc., from their Library of the Future

This is the 100th Etext file presented by Project Gutenberg, and
is presented in cooperation with World Library, Inc., from their
Library of the Future and Shakespeare CDROMS.  Project Gutenberg
often releases Etexts that are NOT placed in the Public Domain!!

Shakespeare

*This Etext has certain copyright implications you should read!*
```

Expected Output:

```
The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Complete Works of William Shakespeare, by
William Shakespeare sn This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with almost no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or re-use it under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included
with this eBook or online at www.gutenberg.org ** This is a COPYRIGHTED Project Gutenberg eBook, Details Below Please follow the copyright guidelines in this file.Title: The Complete Works of William Shakespeare Author: William Shakespeare Posting Date: September 1, 2011 [EBook #100]
Release Date: January, 1994 Language: English START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK COMPLETE WORKS--WILLIAM SHAKESPEARE Produced by World Library, Inc., from their Library of the Future This is the 100th Etext file presented by Project Gutenberg, and is presented in cooperation with World Library, Inc., from their Library of the Future and Shakespeare CDROMS.  Project Gutenberg often releases Etexts that are NOT placed in the Public Domain!! Shakespeare *This Etext has certain copyright implications you should read!*
```

Comment: Post example of input and expected output. Also don't post text/code as image/link ([more info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)). Use [edit] option to correct your post.

Comment: @Pshemo i need all the line breaks, punctuation's to be removed and paragraph to be appended to the previous paragraphs. that is a everything as a single paragraph

Comment: That still is not very clear. You claim "all the line breaks" but that would mean we would get single line which is not the case here since your expected output has four lines. How did you recognize which line separators should stay? You also wrote that all punctuation's should be removed, but we can see `,` before `by [linebreak] William Shakespeare`, not to mention `Release Date: January, 1994`.

Comment: sorry for not providing the info last time,

Suppose the input is=
hello, how are you today
how was school today, what did you have for food?
this star needs to be removed **** 

My required output should be =
hello how are you today how was school today what did  you have for food this star needs to be removed 

Please help @Pshemo

Comment: Try `replaceAll("\\s*\\R\\s*", " ")`

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the words, you can search for words with \w and concatenate them.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final String input = "hello, how are you today how was school today, what did you have for food? this star needs to be removed ****";
    final String regex = "\\w+";
    final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);

    String output = "";
    while (m.find()) {
        output += m.group(0)+" ";
    }
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

result:

```
hello how are you today how was school today what did you have for food this star needs to be removed
```

Answer (score 0):

Use String literal escapes, for the real tab, line feed. And not to forget the carriage return (on Windows).

```
String text = value.toString()
    .replaceAll("(\r?\n){2}", "§") // Two line breaks will become a real line break.
    .replaceAll("[\t\r\n]+", " ") // White space will become a real space.
    .replace("§", "\n"); // The real line breaks.
```

Instead of `§` one might use some esoteric character `uFEFF`.

Will turn

```
Good Morning,

How are you?
I am fine.
```

Into

```
Good Morning,
How are you? I am fine.
```